# Will an office chair that promotes better posture help with sleep apnea?

Tags: sleep-apnea

I'm a software engineer who has pretty bad posture while sitting at my desk all day. I was wondering if getting a more ergonomic chair that promotes better posture will help with my sleep apnea at night? I'm pretty sure a lot of my breathing problems are because my chin tilts forward against my chest and blocks my airway. Can a more ergonomic chair help sleep apnea?

Comment: As written, your question was off topic here. We don't provide recommendations or advice. So I edited it to make it an actual health question. If you dislike my edit you can revert it, but that will likely result in your question being closed as off topic.

Comment: Definitely better, but perhaps could be edited further since ergonomic chairs can help improve posture if properly used; I think the fundamental question is whether improving posture could affect sleep apnea.  @Chris is that what you mean?

Comment: Sleep apnea is a recently defined condition (just about fifty years ago) and science is yet to make great discoveries about it. Therefore there are no definite root causes explaining it, but there are known and suspected factors for sure. It's hardly one single factor, though, so you'd better address all factors, rather than rely on a single one, such as the proper sitting posture. It might have positive enough, but it very well might not be sufficient on its own, to even notice any difference.